# EventMachine change delay in a periodic timer inside the block

Tags: ruby, timer, eventmachine

Call a periodic timer and when an error occurs inside the block change this the periodic timer delay. Can i use periodic timer or the best way is an add_timer ?

Hi, i want to do this:

```
EventMachine.run
    EventMachine.add_periodic_timer 1   
    //read from a input
    //if error set timer to 20s
    //if ok set timer to 1s 
    end
end
```

How to?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `PeriodicTimer` object yourself, and call its accessor `interval=` to set the interval:

```
EventMachine.run do
  timer = EventMachine::PeriodicTimer.new(1) do
    puts "Timer fired at #{Time.now}"
  end
  # timer.interval = 1
  # timer.interval = 20
end
```

Comment: yes i've found it some minutes ago! http://eventmachine.rubyforge.org/EventMachine/PeriodicTimer.html#interval-instance_method thanks!